Using Excel for VLOOKUP and WildCard Not Working
Can you please help me discover why VLOOKUP with Wildcard is not working. I have googled for hours and tried everything.
Using:
=VLOOKUP("*"& E2 &"*",$H$2:$I$3,2,0)

It does work when E2 (the look up cell) is an exact match to the keyword, but not otherwise.
Excel Example

Sample:



Date
Tags
SubCat
Vendor
Description
Amount




3/4/2019
Food
Groceries
Hannaford Market
TST* HANNAFORD DBT CRD 0000 03/03/19 22167640 C#5055
 $170.00


3/4/2019
Food
Dinning Out
Not Found
TST* PRICE CHOP DBT CRD 0000 03/03/19 22167640 #5055
 $ 40.09


3/4/2019
Food
Dinning Out
Pizzeria Downtown
PIZZERIA DO DBT CRD 0000 03/02/19 161146526 C#5055
 $ 86.32






Keywords
Vendor




Hannaford
Hannaford Market


pizzeria
Pizzeria Downtown




Hmmm when I pasted this the asterisks did not show. So for above… that is quote then asterisk then quote

Your logic is incorrect. Your formula is looking for the contents of E2 within the range H2:H3. You need to read about how wild cards work.

I have used this Markdown_Table_Generator as per the Stackoverflow, images are not good for users trying to post solutions. You can use that mentioned link, its easy to use. You just need to copy the data from your excel and paste in the website, click submit to generate copy and paste in your OP. Hope it helps.!

Also, your VLOOKUP() function is not working because, the lookup value you have is a string of words while the keywords is one single word here. this should have worked the other way around using wildcard. What I am trying to say is, if you had used this =VLOOKUP("*"&H2&"*",$E$2:$F$4,2,0) in cell J2 to return the amount then this would work. I know this is not what you want but this is for an example to make you understand how VLOOKUP() with wildcard operator Asterix works in Excel

Instead of using VLOOKUP() its better to use XLOOKUP() function in your context of searching the relevant keywords and return the corresponding vendors:


=XLOOKUP(1,1-ISERR(SEARCH($H$2:$H$3,E2)),I$2:I$3,"Not Found")


And if you intent to use VLOOKUP() only then try using the following:


=IFERROR(TOCOL(VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(E2," "),$H$2:$I$3,2,0),2),"Not Found")


Or, Using LOOKUP() function :
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(SEARCH($H$2:$H$3,E2)),$I$2:$I$3),"Not Found")


Or Could use the following, but it will show blank if nothing is found:
=TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($H$2:$H$3,E2)),$I$2:$I$3,""))


Note that I have used 1-ISERR() which is equivalent to ISNUMBER(), you can use ISNUMBER() in place of the former as well!

One more thing it is better to add boundaries before and after the keyword:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$H$2:$H$3&" "," "&E2&" ")),I$2:I$3,"Not Found")


XLOOKUP() function doesn't needs the other functions when there is no match to return a Not Found !


Thank you so much for this.  Question:  Does one of these work best for a wildcard within words rather than just a match for a full word with spaces on either side?  Like if I have "electric-company" vs "electric company"?

Hello @brando none of the solutions posted above by any of us is going to work, as this is completely different. What we can do, is we can SUBSTITUTE() the character with a space. Try using this one now: =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$H$2:$H$4&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(E2,"-"," ")&" ")),I$2:I$4,"Not Found")

Instead of VLOOKUP, I suggest using INDEX(...,MATCH(...
=INDEX($M$2:$M$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$2:$L$3,E2)),0))

You can use the formula evaluation tool to follow the logic.

Recursive fun
(A bit verbose alternative, similar to Ron's)
Assuming you have Microsoft 365, we could use a recursive matching function.
Caveat: Due to the current limits, this method will work only if the lookup table has 341 rows or less (=QUOTIENT(1024, 2 parameters + 1).

For convenience, define the lookup values as a table. Here I have named it as Vendor_Lookup
You can enter keywords with wildcards (? and *) - such as for Electric company in the example.

Enter the matching function, here it is named find_first as it will find the first match.

In Name manager, enter a new item with name find_first
Enter the following as a refers to: =LAMBDA(lookup_table,text, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TAKE(lookup_table, 1, 1), text)), TAKE(lookup_table, 1, -1), IF(ROWS(lookup_table) = 1, "Not found", find_first(DROP(lookup_table, 1), text))))


In the first cell of Vendor column, enter the following, providing the whole range for description:
=find_first(Vendor_Lookup,E2:E5)


Here's function in expanded form:
TAKE(lookup_table, 1, 1) is lookup value and TAKE(lookup_table, 1, -1) is the return value.
TAKE function - Microsoft Support
=LAMBDA(lookup_table, text,
    IF(
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TAKE(lookup_table, 1, 1), text)),
        TAKE(lookup_table, 1, -1),
        IF(
            ROWS(lookup_table) = 1,
            "Not found",
            find_first(DROP(lookup_table, 1), text)
        )
    )
)




Non-recursive
Add a function find_all_matches in Name Manager in the similar manner as above:

Unformatted version
=LAMBDA(lookup_table,text, LET(match_1, LAMBDA(row_, LET(pos, SEARCH(TAKE(row_, 1, 1), text), IF(ISNUMBER(pos), TAKE(row_, 1, -1), pos))), matches, BYROW(lookup_table, match_1), errors_removed, TOCOL(matches, 2), joined, TEXTJOIN(" OR ", , errors_removed), result, IFERROR(joined, "Not found"), result))

=LAMBDA(lookup_table, text,
    LET(
        match_1, LAMBDA(row_,
            LET(
                pos, SEARCH(TAKE(row_, 1, 1), text),
                IF(ISNUMBER(pos), TAKE(row_, 1, -1), pos)
            )
        ),
        matches, BYROW(lookup_table, match_1),
        errors_removed, TOCOL(matches, 2),
        joined, TEXTJOIN(" OR ", , errors_removed),
        result, IFERROR(joined, "Not found"),
        result
    )
)


